# Does swing have a print dialog?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I looked at [the official printing lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html), and the print dialog is from awt. Does swing have a print dialog too? So that the look and feel of the print dialog is the same as the rest of my swing application.

Comment: The short answer is no